# there is no attribute "placeholder" and there is no attribute "autocomplete"

Tags: html, doctype, w3c, w3c-validation

I have the following errors on my page, when validated with http://validator.w3.org/
 there is no attribute "placeholder"
 there is no attribute "autocomplete"

in details it says:

> Line 59, Column 81: there is no attribute "placeholder"
>   …rd" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder=" What" autocomplete="off"  />
>   ✉
>   You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute,
>   (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both
>   allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this
>   attribute. If you received this error when using the  element
>   to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid
>   flash.

the html tag is here: `<input name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder=" What" autocomplete="off"  />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using html5 then you should use normal doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
</head>
<body>
  <input name="keyword" id="keyword" type="text" style="width:500px;" placeholder=" What" autocomplete="off" />
</body>
</html>
```

if you are using html4 or anything else then you can use following one of this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

For more info..

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-doctype

Answer (score 1):

make sure your using the html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`
And that the validator is validating HTML5

Comment: i have <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> on my site.

Comment: when select DOCTYPE HTML5 experimental the above error disappear, but this warning: DOCTYPE Override in effect!

The detected DOCTYPE Declaration "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">" has been suppressed and the DOCTYPE for "HTML5" inserted instead, but even if no errors are shown below the document will not be Valid until you update it to reflect this new DOCTYPE.

Comment: So whats happening is... You have a page that is mixed html... old and new... The w3c validator only validates.. All old or all new html standards (i believe)... So your trying to validate new html5 attributes on old html.. If you MUST validate it... Either remove the html5 supported attributes and use the old validator.. OR update the entire page to html5 standards and use the new validator...

Comment: with <!DOCTYPE HTML> the w3c validator passed my page, here is no error now. I was come to know about these errors when trying to put the Google Analytic tracking code and that was not installed. 1 of expert told me about these errors. now let me check that GA tracking is working or not. and what new validatory can I use? can you suggest?

Comment: html5.validator.nu also validated my site